# Permissions Rebuild fails

Tags: 7

After I installed a quiz module on my Drupal 7 site, it asked me to rebuild permissions. when I try to rebuild it throws this error:

[image]

I've tried everything that I found online, including:

- increasing web server RAM
- max_execution_time = 1600
- max_input_time = 180
- max_input_nesting_level = 300
- memory_limit = 512M
- disabling batch mode from node.module core file

nothing seems to work.

There are about 600k records in the node table. I know this is a lot, and probably it causes my issue, but what is the workaround? How can I rebuild permissions with this many nodes easily?

Comment: Open a JS console when running this. You should get more info as to the error there.

Comment: Nothing useful there

Comment: Check your logs then. Drupal, PHP and Apache. Potentially your DB logs as well, though usually DB errors will make themselves known in the PHP logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever that "Illegal access" Ajax error comes from, I recommend to rebuild node access from the command line instead. With Drush the following command should do it.

```
$ drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'
```

---

With that many (600k) records in your database it may also be better to have that done by some more advanced process like the one provided by the [Node Access Rebuild Progressive](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access_rebuild_progressive) module. It also provides its own Drush command.

```
$ drush node-access-rebuild-progressive
```

> #### Approach
>
> The module works by processing nodes in chunks, from highest node.nid
>   to lowest, until all nodes have been recomputed, storing the last
>   processed nid in a variable (d7) / as state (d8). This ensure no nodes
>   can be skipped, while avoiding having to populate a Queue or other
>   equivalent mechanism, which can be heavy in itself.

Comment: Finally it reached the end. But it throwed this error:

"Processed 1000 of 1000 nodes - Total: 610000/610000 (610024)
Processed 24 of 24 nodes - Total: 610024/610024 (610024)
PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away database.inc:2171^[[1;33;40m^[[1m[warning]^[[0m
PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header           ^[[1;33;40m^[[1m[warning]^[[0m
dbase.incatabase.inc:2171"

and it still says "Illegal Access" :/

Comment: @Dito – Yeah maybe you need to raise MySQL execution time or something like that. Difficult to tell from afar. Seems progressive rebuild is a nice workaround.